# Ubuntu One: file modified dates versus synchronization date

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have installed Ubuntu One application on two devices:

1) Laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 (about two years ago);

2) Destop PC with Xubuntu 12.04 (added about 2 weeks ago).

I've just realized that on the new desktop PC the date and the hour of all the Ubuntu One files is set as the date and hour of the first sync (e.g. 2013-12-27), wereas with the web login the date is correct (e.g. 2013-07-27). I checked on Ubuntu One help and this behaviour appears intentional, but this is a very big problem in order to manage my documents.

Can someone suggest me some trick?

Answer (score 1):

There is no trick. Ubuntu One does not synchronize file creation/modification/access times, nor file permissions.

When downloading files to a new system, the file will have the creation/modification time of when it was written to disk on that system.